# Find the earliest date from a series of inputs

Tags: c, datetime

I need to find minimal date (year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds).

My code is working, but it looks terrible and it's very long. What can I do to avoid this ladder and make my code readable? (I want to use only `<stdio.h>`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct DateTime_s {
    int year , month , day ;
    int hours , minutes , seconds ;
} DateTime ;
void DataTime(const DateTime *mas , int x){
    int i;
    struct DateTime_s min={40000,400000,4000000,400000,400000,4000};
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        if(mas[i].year<min.year){
            min=mas[i];
        }
        else if(mas[i].year==min.year){
            if(mas[i].month<min.month){
                min=mas[i];
            }
            else if(mas[i].month==min.month){
                if(mas[i].day<min.day){
                    min=mas[i];
                }
                else if(mas[i].day==min.day){
                    if(mas[i].hours<min.hours){
                        min=mas[i];
                    }
                    else if(mas[i].hours==min.hours){
                        if(mas[i].minutes<min.minutes){
                            min=mas[i];
                        }
                        else if(mas[i].minutes==min.minutes){
                            if(mas[i].seconds<min.seconds){
                                min=mas[i];
                            }
                            else if(mas[i].seconds==min.seconds){
                                min=mas[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",min.year,min.month,min.day,min.hours,min.minutes,min.seconds);
}

int main() {
    int x,i;
    struct DateTime_s mas[50001];
    scanf("%d",&x);
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        struct DateTime_s b;
        scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",&b.year, &b.month,&b.day,&b.hours,&b.minutes,&b.seconds);
        mas[i]=b;
    }
    DataTime(mas,x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How were you planning on handling switches to/from Daylight Savings Time or other time zone shenanigans?  You may not think this is important now, but I guarantee it will come and bite you at some point.

Comment: Why is the datetime variable called `mas`?  Is that a short form of something?

Answer (score 9):

### Use Helper Functions

Although my coding style hasn’t caught on, I think ternary `?` `:` expressions lend themselves very well to algorithms like this.

```
const DateTime* DateTime_min( const DateTime* const a,
                              const DateTime* const b )
{
    return (( a->year    > b->year    ) ? b :
            ( b->year    > a->year    ) ? a :
            ( a->month   > b->month   ) ? b :
            ( b->month   > a->month   ) ? a :
            ( a->day     > b->day     ) ? b :
            ( b->day     > a->day     ) ? a :
            ( a->hours   > b->hours   ) ? b :
            ( b->hours   > a->hours   ) ? a :
            ( a->minutes > b->minutes ) ? b :
            ( b->minutes > a->minutes ) ? a :
            ( a->seconds > b->seconds ) ? b :
                                          a
           );
}
```

I also separate out the code to print a `DataTime` structure.  This version prints in ISO format.

```
int DateTime_fprint( FILE* const out, const DateTime* const x )
{
    return fprintf( out,
                    "%04d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d",
                    x->year,
                    x->month,
                    x->day,
                    x->hours,
                    x->minutes,
                    x->seconds
                  );
}
```

This lets your `DataTime` become:

```
const DateTime* DataTime( const DateTime *const mas, const size_t n )
{
    const DateTime* min = mas;
    
    for ( const DateTime* p = mas + 1; p < mas + n; ++p ) {
        min = DateTime_min( min, p );
    }
    
    return min;
}
```

This version returns a pointer to the minimal element, which you can pass to the output function, or do other things with.

In C, you could also write the function in C99 style, as

```
const DateTime* DataTime( const size_t n, const DateTime mas[n] );
```

In this version of the program, there was no problem returning a `const` pointer to the minimal element.  If you need to be able to modify the minimum element that you find, so that you can either pass in a `const` array or get a modifiable element, your options include:

- Write two functions with different names, one of which takes a non-`const` pointer and the other of which takes a `const` pointer.  (In languages derived from C, this could be an overload with the same name.)  The non-`const` version might call the `const` version and cast its return value to a non-`const` pointer.  Since the maintainer of this code knows the internal implementation details, they know it’s actually safe, and the library itself can present a type-safe public interface.
- Accept a `const` array, but return an argmin value for the index of the minimal element, which you can still use on your modifiable array without violating type safety.
- Cast the returned element from `const DateTime*` to `(DateTime*)`, if you know for sure that neither of your inputs was `const`.

### Check for Buffer Overflow

I mean it.  Always, *always*, ***always*** bounds check your array access in C.  It is a huge security bug to let the user tell you how much data to write into a fixed-size buffer, and not check for buffer overflow.

If nothing else, throw in an `assert` to crash your program before this happens.  This is vastly preferable to dealing with the kind of bugs memory corruption causes.

```
int main(void)
{
    static DateTime mas[NDATES];
    size_t n = 0;
    
    scanf( "%zu", &n );
    assert( n > 0 && n < NDATES );
    
    for( DateTime* b = mas, *const endp = mas+n; b < endp; ++b ){
        scanf( "%d %d %d %d %d %d",
               &b->year,
               &b->month,
               &b->day,
               &b->hours,
               &b->minutes,
               &b->seconds );
    }
    DateTime_fprint( stdout, DataTime( mas, n ) );    
    fputs( "\n", stdout );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Another solution would be to declare `mas` dynamically, with `calloc`, once you know the required size.  Again, check for overflow, both of the buffer itself and its size parameter.

### Avoid Copying Arrays Unnecessarily

There are a few other tweaks to the algorithm here, but the main one was avoiding the extra copy of

```
mas[i]=b;
```

inside the initialization loop, which copies every element of the array from memory to memory an extra time.  This version instead reads each element into its permanent location in memory.

In the code above, I declare an end pointer to tell the loop when to terminate.  This is because neither clang 13.0.0 nor gcc 11.2 is smart enough to figure out that `mas+n` is a constant when `n` is not declared `const`.  It’s hard to actually prove that the loop can never change the value of `n` during its execution.  (In fact, there will always be cases where it doesn’t, but no computer program can ever prove it doesn’t.)  You’ll notice that, in `DataTime`, where I declare both the `mas` and `n` arguments `const`, the compiler does not need this hint, and I can just write the termination clause as `p < mas+n`.  It’s a good example of how declaring data `const` is not just safer, but enables optimizations.  (The extra overhead is negligible, though.)

This could be a reason to move the initialization into a separate function, such as

```
 DateTime_read( mas, n, stdin );
```

Or to make `n` a static single assignment with

```
const size_t n = read_input_size(stdin);
```

It would also be possible to write the loop to increment a `aize_t i` value and include, within the loop, the alias

```
DateTime* const b = &mas[i];
```

You would then use `&b->year`, etc. as above.  This is basically equivalent, and would make it easier to do multiple things with `i` within the loop.

##### ETA:

Peter Cordes in the comments identified the reason that compilers cannot properly optimize your original loop.  You have

```
scanf("%d",&x);
for(i=0;i<x;i++){
```

Passing `&x` to `scanf` made it escape the loop.  For all the compiler knows, that external function `scanf` that it knows nothing about could do anything with `&x`, such as store it in a global variable and change the value of `x` whenever you call it again inside your loop.

The overhead here is pretty minimal, but this is another reason you want to write variables as static single assignments, and possibly move loops into helper functions whose parameters can be passed by value or given the `restrict` qualifier.  Either would make it possible for the compiler to deduce that the body of the loop cannot modify its control variable, and better optimize the loop.  (My workaround essentially introduced a different static single assignment, but it probably would have been better to write `n` as one in the first place.)

### Avoid Reinventing the Wheel

The `<time.h>` header has a `struct tm` that’s very similar to `DateTime` in this program.  It could be used to convert input time strings to timestamps, which can be compared or sorted as integers, and converted back into a human-readable time string for output.

### Consider a Different Naming Convention

You named your function `DataTime`, and I left that unchanged, but I gave all the new functions that manipulate `DateTime` structures, names like `DateTime_min` and `DateTime_fprint`.  The name `DataTime` is not very descriptive of what the function does, and it is easy to confuse with `DateTime`.

It’s a common convention to give data types and modules names that start with capital letters, and name functions and variables in snake_case or camelCase.  I split the difference, treating `DateTime_` as a prefix for all the names I added and writing everything after it in snake_case.  So pick a convention that you like, and stick with it.

### Do at Least a Little Parsing, Maybe

The input format you’re implicitly expecting is used widely for programming-contest problems, and not so much in the real world.  With an unformatted soup of numbers as your input, you can’t give useful error messages or recover if your input is badly-formatted.

If you’re not trying to win a programming contest by eliminating as much error-checking as possible, you might consider checking that each date is on its own input line, and checking the return value of `scanf()` to make sure that each line correctly parsed. That way, if any input line does not correctly parse, you can give an error message with a line number.  It would then be possible to find the error in the input file.

Another common idiom is to read a chunk of input into a buffer, and parse that line of input with `sscanf`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132538/discussion-between-davislor-and-peter-cordes).

Answer (score 4):

One of the most effective tools at improving readability is functions!

```c
DateTime *min_dt(const DateTime *a, const DateTime *b) {
    if ( a->year    != b->year    ) return (DateTime *)( a->year    < b->year    ? a : b );
    if ( a->month   != b->month   ) return (DateTime *)( a->month   < b->month   ? a : b );
    if ( a->day     != b->day     ) return (DateTime *)( a->day     < b->day     ? a : b );
    if ( a->hours   != b->hours   ) return (DateTime *)( a->hours   < b->hours   ? a : b );
    if ( a->minutes != b->minutes ) return (DateTime *)( a->minutes < b->minutes ? a : b );
    if ( a->seconds != b->seconds ) return (DateTime *)( a->seconds < b->seconds ? a : b );
    return a;
}

void DataTime(const DateTime *mas, size_t n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return;  // Or whatever

    const DateTime *min = &mas[0];
    for (size_t i=1; i<n; ++i)
        min = min_dt(min, &mas[i]);

    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, the `const` removal makes the lines a bit long. But it's required for the function to work with both pointers to constants and pointers to non-constants.<sup>[1]</sup> The issue could be dodged by returning a boolean or a tri-state value.

```c
int cmp_dt(const DateTime *a, const DateTime *b) {
    if ( a->year    != b->year    ) return a->year    < b->year    ? -1 : +1;
    if ( a->month   != b->month   ) return a->month   < b->month   ? -1 : +1;
    if ( a->day     != b->day     ) return a->day     < b->day     ? -1 : +1;
    if ( a->hours   != b->hours   ) return a->hours   < b->hours   ? -1 : +1;
    if ( a->minutes != b->minutes ) return a->minutes < b->minutes ? -1 : +1;
    if ( a->seconds != b->seconds ) return a->seconds < b->seconds ? -1 : +1;
    return 0;
}

void DataTime(const DateTime *mas, size_t n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return;  // Or whatever

    size_t min_i = 0;
    for (size_t i=1; i<n; ++i) {
        if ( cmp_dt(&mas[min_i], &mas[i]) < 0 ) {
            min_i = i;
        }
    }

    const DateTime *min = &mas[min_i];

    // ...
}
```

Bonus: This is more reusable! You could use it for a sorting or searching.

Don't worry about performance. Under `-Ofast` on an x86/x86-64, `gcc` inlines the function, performs only one comparison per field (instead of the two found in the source code), and it doesn't even bother generating the tri-state return since we only need a boolean (less than or not). [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nW1P5rjon), lines 52..70.

---

1. It's far better to remove the cast in one place that's easily testable than to force the caller to cast away the `const` themselves at multiple call sites. It's far too likely to get this wrong, either from the start (in ways that are possibly subtle and not immediately detected), or in the long run as a the code is maintained and modified.

   Some might suggest creating duplicate functions, one for `const` types and one for non-`const` types. This, however, violate the fundamental Don't Repeat Yourself principle. And to what end? To avoid accidentally writing to a read-only variable? There is such a low chance of that happening, especially compared to getting a var or type name wrong. And the repercussions usually amount to an easily debuggable crash the first time you run the program.

   Sure, that's a risk, but you can't entirely eliminate risks. You can only strive to minimize both the risks and the consequences of those risks.

Comment: You inspired me to come up with my own refactoring.

Comment: I have to respectfully, but firmly, disagree with the function casting away `const` on its return value, however. First, you don’t even need to cast away `const` in this program. More importantly, it’s dangerous. The programmer could pass in a `DateTime` that genuinely is const, possibly stored in a read-only segment of memory, get back a non-`const` pointer, modify its contents, and crash the program. If you really, truly need to shoot yourself in the foot that way, you should have to do it explicitly and blatantly, by having the caller cast `const` away on the return value.

Comment: @Davislor It's a standard practice to avoid `const` on return values (e.g. `strchr`, `index`). The risk are quite small, and the benefits are huge. It's so much worse to have to maintain two separate copy of the same function. Especially when you consider that `"a"` is a `char*`, not `const char*`. This means we already have to deal with lack of `const` on return values in a "million" places in every single program. And it means it's an immense exaggeration to say that using `"a"` or `strchr` is "shooting yourself in the foot".

Comment: It hasn’t been a standard practice for more than thirty years. The **only** reason `strchr` does that is that it’s older than the `const` keyword, and the standard library couldn’t break backward compatibility. C++ does define an overload for `strchr` that returns `const char*`. The fact that, for backward compatibility with K&R C, you can still assign a string constant to a `char*` rather than a `const char*` is a perfect analogy: never, ever do that in new code! It’s a legacy of the ’70s, not a model to follow today. If you actually modify those pointers, it’s undefined behavior.

Comment: @Davislor, Put simply, I get var and type names wrong on a daily basis. But I don't think I've ever tried to write to a read-only variable by accident. One clearly needs more protection than the other. // Undefined behaviour just means the spec doesn't define what it does, and the compiler are free to do as they please. The compilers on systems with virtual memory very clearly define the behaviour: A protection fault. So, if for some reason I actually write to a read-only by accident, all that will happen is a clean death. Something that will probably happen the first time I run the program.

Comment: In C++, I’d strongly recommend `const` and non-`const` overloads.  C does have very limited support for overloads, but if you really need both a modifiable return value and the ability to pass in non-modifiable data, you can name it `DateTime_min_m` or something. Or you could return a `struct`, or return a comparison value as you suggested, which is a much better solution.

Comment: @Davislor This is the second time you brought up C++, but what you would do in C++ is irrelevant. This answer is for C programs specifically.

Comment: @Davislor & ikegami, with `_Generic` magic, a wrapper around `min_dt()` can achieve `const` correctness, without repeated code all in C.  You both win.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah, that’s what I was thinking of when I talked about limited support for overloading. I don’t think that’s an option here, unfortunately. The C17 standard says, “No two generic associations in the same generic selection shall specify compatible types.” I have not tested whether any compilers would support this as an extension. Even if compilers do, it’s really intended to allow portable implementations of `<math.h>`.

Comment: @Davislor gcc version 11.2.0 well distinguished `char *` from `const char *`.  In this context, I do not think  those 2 types are compatible with each other.  Perhaps you are right though,  `_Generic` implementations are still nascent.

Answer (score 2):

This code is not robust:

> ```
> scanf("%d",&x);
> for(i=0;i<x;i++){
> ```

We're ignoring the return value from `scanf()` and just assuming that `x` is assigned.  We need to be testing - for example:

```
if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1) {
    fputs("Error reading input\n", stderr);
    return 1;
}
for (int i = 0;  i < x;  ++i) {
```

Similarly, if the other `scanf()` doesn't return 6, then our structure `b` is not initialised and we can't safely use its value.

---

[Ikegami's answer](/a/272215/75307) shows how to create a comparison function for two `DateTime` values (with an interface like `strcmp()`), but an alternative inline loop takes advantage of `continue` to move to the next iteration:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < x;  ++i) {
     const struct DateTime this_one = mas[i];
     if (this_one.year < min.year) {
         min = this_one;
     }
     if (this_one.year != min.year) {
         continue;
     }
     /* if we get here, years are equal */
     if (this_one.month < min.month) {
         min = this_one;
     }
     if (this_one.month != min.month) {
         continue;
     }
     /* if we get here, years and months are equal */
    ⋮

    ⋮
    /* until we get to seconds */
}
```

Comment: You can also place a `continue` in the `if`s where you assign `min`.

Comment: You can, but since you then need to `continue` if the field is greater than the other object's, it made sense to reduce the duplication.  Both forms are likely to compile to the same code with any reasonable optimising compiler, so choose whichever you think is clearest.

Answer (score 2):

**Priorities**

OP has "What can I do to avoid this ladder and make my code readable?" is common misguided aim.  Top goal should be: function correctness.

**Correct compare**

I assert that the multi-level compares of the 6 members is fundamentally wrong as is does not compare time-stamps properly when member values are not in the primary range.

**Out of primary range values**

How should code compare Yesterday:[24:00:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00) versus Today:00:00:00?

In comparing time, the timestamps should **not** be assumed to only encode primary time values.

A common work-around is to convert to a uniform scale - the number of seconds - then the compare is trivial.

```
long long dt_day(int y, int m, int d); //TBD code

long long dt_secs(const DateTime *mas) {
  long long sum = dt_day(mas->year, mas->month, mas->day);
  sum = sum*24 + mas->hours;
  sum = sum*60 + mas->minutes;
  sum = sum*60 + mas->seconds;
  return sum;
}

void DataTime(const DateTime *mas , int x){
  if (x > 0) {
    int min_index = 0;
    long long min = dt_secs(mas[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
      long long t = dt_secs(mas[i]);
      if (t < min) {
        min = t;
        min_index = i;
      }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", //
        mas[min_index].year, mas[min_index].month, mas[min_index].day, //
        mas[min_index].hours, mas[min_index].minutes, mas[min_index].seconds);
  }  
}
```

Of course there are nuance issues like [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) and non-[Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) and odd cases like [February 30th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_non-standard_dates#February_30).  Further issues occur when `int` and `long long` are both 64-bit.

Comment: I’d made the same suggestion, but it’s buried in the middle of a long post. The algorithm I used (and I believe the OP’s, although I haven’t rigorously checked) works *if*, and only if, the program maintains the invariant that all dates are formatted correctly. But this is hard to ensure, unless you modify the instances only through an API that maintains the invariants. Here, we aren’t. We could also warn: if you set the date to something invalid, all bets are off.

Comment: A good solution to the problem of weird time zones is to interpret all times as UTC. Since the problem statement doesn’t specify a different one, it appears that the OP is allowed to do so.

Comment: According to ISO 8601, the beginning of the branch cut is always 00, thus 24 is invalid. I would argue that raising an exception is the most correct approach _vs_ silently trying to correct. (Otoh, leap seconds can have a value of 60.)

Comment: @Neil My ISO 8601 is old given [Earlier versions of the standard allowed "24:00"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) corresponding to the end of a day, but this is explicitly disallowed by the 2019 revision.}  IAC, OP's `DateTime` is not spec'd as ISO 8601.  C's `struct tm` accounts for out of primary range values with `mkitme()`  and can serve as a model as to what is allowed here.